# How to write a custom CICategoryReduction filter

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to write a custom CoreImage filter that will calculate an image's bounding box on a device's GPU.

In essence I'm looking for a filter that returns a rectangle based on an input image, rather than a new image. From the different list of available filters I noticed that the only built-it filters that provide this functionality are those listed under CICategoryReduction.

However I couldn't find any code sample showing how to built a custom "reduction" filter, rather I found many filters that adjust an input image and either warp or color it.

Does anyone have an example or an idea how I could approach writing such a filter?

Comment: Actually it looks like `CICategoryReduction` filters *do* return a `CIImage` - it's just that they reduce the input into one pixel (or a one pixel array). If you look at `CIFilter`, which is what you will subclass for your filter, you will see that `outputImage` is returning a `CIImage`. I think what you are trying is not what CoreImage is meant to do. The return of a `CIKernel`, no matter what kind, is a `vec4` or typically a pixel value in RGBA.